# Why not reuse validated certificate in two way ssl connection?

Tags: security, ssl, mutual-authentication

I am wondering why client/server certificate, after being validated by CA certificate, can not be added to trust store so that certificates don't need to be passed around and validated in future connection?

Answer (score 0):

1. Because it isn't necessary. If you trust the signer, that is sufficient.
2. Because it isn't sufficient. The certificate would still have to be 'passed around'.

Comment: My understanding is if the request coming from a trusted client (its certificate in trust store) then we don't need to bother to ask signer for validation, please let me know why this not work?

Comment: You can't possibly know that it's coming from a trusted client unless the client provides his certificate.

Comment: The certificate contains the client information, such as FQDN, isn't possible to use these information to identify client?

Comment: If FQDN was sufficient we wouldn't need certificates at all.